# База данных Java

Tags: java, база-данных

Добрый вечер.

Мне нужно написать на языке Java базу данных в графическом режиме, в которой нужно реализовать добавление, изменение, удаление и сортировку данных.

Посоветуйте какие-либо книги, видеоуроки, форумы для решения данной проблемы.

Comment: базу данных? wtf? может субд все-таки?

Comment: Я думаю тут задача на много банальние и надо просто написать псевдо бд, например массив с CRUD операциями....

Comment: Да,да.Скорее всего это она и есть (т.е. " псевдо бд, например массив с CRUD операциями.... ")В силу своей компьютерной безграмотности не смог более точно сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: > "написать на языке Java базу данных в графическом режиме"

Эта фраза - тихий ужас. Как можно быть таким ленивым? Вы даже не потрудились заглянуть на вики, чтоб правильно поставить вопрос...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. Я аналогично по этому вопросу точной информации не нашёл. Пришлось выбирать различную информацию из разных источников и думать самому. Могу помочь куском кода.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Mysql {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    /**
     *
     * Метод осуществляет подключение к базе данных с заданными параметрами
     *
     * @param mysql_login текстовая переменная, является именем пользователя
     * базы данных
     * @param mysql_pass текстовая переменная, является паролем имени
     * пользователя базы данных
     * @param mysql_db текстовая переменная, является именем базы данных, к
     * которой идет подключение
     * @throws SQLException
     *
     */

    public static void connect(String mysql_login, String mysql_pass, String mysql_db) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + mysql_db, mysql_login, mysql_pass);
            System.out.println("The connection was successful.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Метод для запроса в БД
     *
     * @param query Строка запроса в БД
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void com(String query) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Закрытие подключения к БД
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void close() throws SQLException {
        conn.close();
    }
```

Далее с помощью метода запроса в БД добавляй, удаляй, сортируй данные; Но это уже Mysql запросы. По этой теме: [ССЫЛКА](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Entering_queries.html)
По java можно также посмотреть курс [ЛЕКЦИЙ](http://www.lektorium.tv/ssearch/?qstr=Java)
Из книг: "Брюс Эккель. Философия Java" и "Джошуа Блох. Java. Эффективное программирование"

Comment: Благодарствую)